# How to get input from Scala after a certain point in time?

Tags: scala

I'm working on a game written in Scala where the user has to type "BANG" as quickly as possible in order to hunt an animal.

```scala
// ...

println("When you see an animal, type BANG as quickly as possible.")
Thread.sleep(2000 + Random.nextInt(6000))

val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
println("You see an animal!")
val bang = readLine("")
val time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start

if (bang == "BANG" && time <= 1500) {
  // ...you get the point
```

Unfortunately, there's a bug that makes so that you can type "BANG" ahead of time and always win, because it accepts input before the `readLine()`.

I have tried a few different ways of clearing the input. The obvious solution, putting a `readLine()` before `val start = System.currentTimeMillis()`, doesn't work because it forces the user to press enter first.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362522/capture-keypress-in-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard way of clearing stdin with Scala's (or even Java's) API.

You can use this lower-level implementation [`RawConsoleInput`](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/RawConsoleInput/) to clear the buffer though.

It has a `read` method that returns the first character in the standard input, or `-2` if the buffer is clear.

Because it uses "raw input mode", instead of the usual "line mode", keys like Enter, backspace, Ctrl+C will NOT be processed by the operating system, and will remain in the buffer until `read` is called.

```
//drain standard input
while(RawConsoleInput.read(wait = false) >= 0) {
}
```

Signature:

```
/**
* Reads a character from the console without echo.
*
* @param wait
*   <code>true</code> to wait until an input character is available,
*   <code>false</code> to return immediately if no character is available.
* @return
*   -2 if <code>wait</code> is <code>false</code> and no character is available.
*   -1 on EOF.
*   Otherwise an Unicode character code within the range 0 to 0xFFFF.
*/
public static int read (boolean wait) throws IOException
```

Note: make sure you've imported the JNA library.