# How to cause a left click then turn off thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, keylistener

```
    private void runInBackground() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                try {
                    checkPixel();
                } catch (AWTException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void stop() {
    this.running = false;
}

public void start() {
    this.running = true;
}
```

So I have some code someone provided me to monitor the change in color in the middle of the screen. I want to essentially turn on/off `checkPixel()` after I press something like F9 but how can I do this without a GUI because I can't seem to find anything that allows this. I believe KeyListeners only work with GUIs?

EDIT: Ok so instead while I'm checking for pixel changes in the thread. Once a pixel change has been detected I want to cause create a "left click action" in `checkPixel()` then turn off the thread. Any help with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get key press without pressing enter in console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531560/get-key-press-without-pressing-enter-in-console)

Comment: How do I add a KeyListener without a GUI? unless I'm wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901224/listening-for-input-without-focus-in-java ...unfortunately... or you could use a full screen transparent window and then implement a KeyListener. I would probably opt for the full screen transparent window as it will save you a lot of time

Comment: @peggy I have made an edit, could you possibly help with this? maybe this is a more smarter solution. We don't have to start the thread again.

Comment: I'd still use a transparent window/KeyListener but I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish your goal also

Comment: @peggy my new request doesn't require listeners

Comment: are you not referring to using a MouseListener by "create a left click action"?

Comment: @peggy I want to make the program click the mouse, so I'm not listening for a mouse click

Comment: can you be more specific on what you are wanting to do here? Do you care where the click takes place? what is this click supposed to accomplish? the Robot class can create mouse clicks but I'm not sure if this is what you actually want. How do you plan to use a left click to turn off a thread? See this post on creating mouse clicks via Robot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185162/how-to-simulate-a-real-mouse-click-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want functionality provided by JNativeHook library.
The library allows for grabbing a key from the backgrond.