# How to check if a key was pressed in do-while Loop [in Java]

Tags: java, key, do-while, interrupted-exception, keyboardinterrupt

It's a Game where you can "roll the dice"

I want that the number 1-6 is getting spinned in the Console until the Player is pressing a Key. The number that was displayed when pressing, is the number that is going to be selected.

Thank You!

My code looks like that:

```
do {


    System.out.print("\b1");
        Thread.sleep(100);

    if (System.in != null) {
    dice1Player = 1;
    break;

    }



    System.out.print("\b2");
    Thread.sleep(100);

    if (System.in != null) {

    dice1Player = 2;
    break;
}


    System.out.print("\b3");
    Thread.sleep(100);

    if (System.in != null){

    dice1Player = 3;
    break;
    }


    System.out.print("\b4");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    if (System.in != null){

    dice1Player = 4;
    break;
    }

    System.out.print("\b5");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    if (System.in != null){

    dice1Player = 5;
    break;
    }


    System.out.print("\b6");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    if  (System.in != null){

    dice1Player = 6;
    break;
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);

} while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
```

Comment: You can't capture key presses from the standard Java console

Comment: how can i do it in an other way? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Make a GUI application in Javafx or Swing @Sean

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531560/get-key-press-without-pressing-enter-in-console